# How do I get data class object properties in a for loop

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to simplify the code below into a for loop.

```
data class UsbAmp(
    val id : Int,
    val name : String,
    val portnum : Int,
    var hertz_1 : Int,
    var hertz_2 : Int,
    var hertz_3 : Int,
    var hertz_4 : Int,
    var hertz_5 : Int,
    var hertz_6 : Int,
    var hertz_7 : Int,
    var hertz_8 : Int,
    var hertz_9 : Int,
    var hertz_10 : Int
)
```

```
arraySeekBar[0].progress = usbamp.component4()
arraySeekBar[1].progress = usbamp.component5()
arraySeekBar[2].progress = usbamp.component6()
arraySeekBar[3].progress = usbamp.component7()
arraySeekBar[4].progress = usbamp.component8()
arraySeekBar[5].progress = usbamp.component9()
arraySeekBar[6].progress = usbamp.component10()
arraySeekBar[7].progress = usbamp.component11()
arraySeekBar[8].progress = usbamp.component12()
arraySeekBar[9].progress = usbamp.component13()
```

```
arraySeekBar[0].progress = usbamp.hertz_1
arraySeekBar[1].progress = usbamp.hertz_2
arraySeekBar[2].progress = usbamp.hertz_3
arraySeekBar[3].progress = usbamp.hertz_4
arraySeekBar[4].progress = usbamp.hertz_5
arraySeekBar[5].progress = usbamp.hertz_6
arraySeekBar[6].progress = usbamp.hertz_7
arraySeekBar[7].progress = usbamp.hertz_8
arraySeekBar[8].progress = usbamp.hertz_9
arraySeekBar[9].progress = usbamp.hertz_10
```

'arraySeekBar' is an array containing 10 seekbars.

'usbamp' is a data class object.

What should I do?

Comment: What is usbamp.hertz1,2,3 here ?

Comment: usbamp.hertz is dataclass property

Comment: Can these not be combined into a single `List<Int>` property?